# Okhttp use response

Tags: android, asynchronous, okhttp

I am using an asynchronous Okhttp to do request and then use the response to fill in the UI.

My idea was to wait in the main thread for the response and then start a new activity. Is this the best way? If so, how can I wait and access the parsed data of the response in the main thread?

Main activity:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    ...
    HttpHelper client = new HttpHelper();
    String response = client.get("https://www.google.com");
    ...
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message+"\nresponse:\n"+response);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("DATA_GET", client.dataOut);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

HttpHelper class:

```
public class HttpHelper {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String[] dataOut;

    String get(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException{
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                // parsing response
                dataOut = ...;
            }
        });

        return "done";
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No it is a bad way. I recommend using `Retrofit`, it will handle most of the boilerplate networking stuff for you on a background thread and will serve you the response via a callback when it completes.

Comment: could you explain why? with okhttp and enqueue function, the request is not being handled in the main thread.

thanks a lot,

Comment: sorry the double post, but didn't tag you @pat